# XMetaL XSL-FO column layout

Tags: xsl-fo, xmetal

I am now developing a xslfo stylesheet that sets the content to 2-column display, using the RenderX XEP processor. However, I still want to leave the tables as 1-column display.

Indeed, since I am using XEP processor, it will not allow me to put an @span="all" attribute shows the error "fo:block is not a direct child of an fo:flow".

The article is referring to Docbook xslfo, while I am using a custom xslfo that comes with XMetal.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your resulting XSL FO it is hard to understand. But yes, span="all" must be on a structure that is a direct child of flow. If your table is inside other things like a block-container or a block, this can happen and you will get that error.

You can span the table across the two columns only if the block with span="all" is a direct child of fo:flow.

```
<fo:flow>
   <fo:block span="all">I work and will span two columns</fo:block>
   <fo:block-container>
      <fo:block span="all">I will NOT work as I am not a child of fo:flow</fo:block>
   <fo:block-container>
</fo:flow>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin thank you but i could not understand this is the written code in the style sheet this note i want span on the page <xsl:template match="note">
 <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="note" span="all">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </fo:block>
</xsl:template> this code could not work in XMetaL could you please help to how to do that

Comment: Create the entire FO and examine it. You are creating that structure inside something else and it cannot be for a span as all.

Comment: In other words, your source likely has note inside something else whose template is creating another structure and the note block is not a child of root

Comment: Thank you kevin, is there any way to how to do that in Xmetal this code worked in Antenna House but this could not work for XMetaL actually we are stuck kindly guide